# PHP and MySQL echo string only in certain conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a php script to only show a link, when a "user" in a MySQL table is "logged in". What is wrong with the php code which I have tried? Mine is here below:

```
<? 
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
header("location:main_login.php");
}

?>

<html>
<head>
require_once(checklogin.php)
</head>
<body>

<?php
if($myusername == "admin");
echo "<a href="test.html"> Click Me! </a>";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**The $myusername variable comes from the file below which checks the username from a form (on another page) against the mysql table and opens a session.**

```
<?php
ob_start();
$host="-----";// Mysql username 
$password="-----"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="-------"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="-------"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$myusername' and password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){
// Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "login_success.php"
session_register("myusername");
session_register("mypassword"); 
header("location:login_success.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

So to repeat my question: **What exactly is wrong with this block of code**

```
if($myusername == "admin");
echo "<a href="test.html"> Click Me! </a>";
?>
```

**which should recognize the user and display the link**

Comment: which error you are getting with this code ?

Comment: To Saiyam Patel: What is happening is "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/a5994084/public_html/login_success.php on line 19"

Comment: which file is login_success.php in above two script?

Comment: place test.html in single quotes like this ('test.html') not like this ("test.html")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
<?php
    if($myusername == "admin")
    echo "<a href='test.html'> Click Me! </a>";
?>
```

when you start the string with double inverted coma(")  you must have to use single inverted coma(') in that statement if parser found another double inverted coma (") it will consider as a end of string

may be this issue

Comment: This fixed it! Thanks! But the only problem is that the link displays for every user... Oh well, back to the drawing board thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

The cause of the syntax error is a stray `;` after the `if` statement. It should be removed.

```
if($myusername == "admin");
//-----------------------^^
// Error here -- remove that semicolon!
```

There are some other issues here, like the unquoted value in `session_register()`, which should be surrounded in quotes:

```
session_start();
if(!session_is_registered(myusername)){
//-----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^
header("location:main_login.php");
}
```

However, the use of `session_register()` is not recommended.  The proper modern way to set session variables is by using the `$_SESSION` superglobal array.  (see the [deprecation notices in the PHP docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php))

```
// Set a variable
session_start();
$myusername = "admin";
$_SESSION['myusername'] = $myusername;

// Get a variable
// Always call session_start() at the beginning of the script
echo $_SESSION['myusername'];
// admin
```

Comment: Michael, thank you for the help. I have the semicolon in my code and it still gives me the syntax error. Any idea why? Thanks

Comment: also in the first file, he also has semicolon after if statement

Comment: Thanks again for the extra information, instead of setting the variable in this script, shouldn't the require_once allow me to call a variable from that script?

Comment: @user1239304 As long as the variable set in the included file via `require_once()` is at global scope, it will be available to the script which included it.  But if you want the value to persist across a page load, you will need to store it in `$_SESSION`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
if($myusername == "admin")  // semicolon removed
{ 
// use single quotes for href or escape double quotes
echo "<a href='test.html'> Click Me! </a>"; 
}
?
```

Answer (score 0):

place test.html in single quotes like this ('test.html') not like this ("test.html")

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems.
if($myusername == "admin"); // remove this semicolon after if.
And echo " Click Me! "; // remove the double quotes around test.html